# Can Google track placemarks made with the Google Earth API?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

What I mean by this is, since your browser doesn't cache the Google Earth Javascript API locally, all calls you make to the API have to go to Google's server.  So if you create a placemark at some Lat & Long in the API, those coordinates get sent to Google.  I am just wondering if my understanding of this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API is loaded locally into the browser. That information is not sent to Google.